# SQL Linked Server Update Openquery syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, openquery, pervasive

I am trying to update data in a PervasiveSQL backend (Sage ERP system) from SQL Server 2008 R2 via a Linked Server setup. Below are details and error msg returned... The kicker is that the update statement works on a development box just fine, very similar setup. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

Environment:

- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise (Cloud server, Rackspace)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86) Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)
- Sage Timberline ERP running with Pervasive SQL v.10 backend

Setup:
We have a LINKED SERVER setup in SQL Server 2008, using a 32-bit Timberline Driver (OBDC)
Linked server is using a MSDASQL provider with the following two properties set to TRUE, “Allow inprocess” and “Non Transacted Updates”

Issue:
We can successfully pull data, see query below, from linked server.  We can successfully browse objects via the linked server in SSMS.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (TLLINKSERVER, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 where JOBID = ''00-00-111111''')
```

However the `UPDATE` statement below returns the following error.

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(TLLINKSERVER, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE JOBID = ''00-00-111111''')
SET DATEFIELD = '2013-07-15'
```

Error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TLLINKSERVER" returned
>   message "[Sage Timberline Office][Sage Timberline Office ODBC
>   Driver]Syntax Error.". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
>   "TLLINKSERVER" returned message "[Sage Timberline Office][Sage
>   Timberline Office ODBC Driver]UPDATE "\SERVER1\Company
>   Data\DATA\COMPANY1\"<< ??? >>."TABLE1" SET "DATEFIELD1"=? WHERE
>   "JOBID"=? AND "DATEFIELD1"=?".
>   Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TLLINKSERVER" could not
>   UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]".

Comment: "Very similar" setup - could you enumerate how they're not identical?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make things easier? Does PervasiveSQL not support direct updates via a linked server?

```
UPDATE TLLINKSERVER...TABLE1 
  SET DATEFIELD = '2013-07-15'
  WHERE JOBID = '00-00-111111';
```

Or maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(TLLINKSERVER, 'UPDATE TABLE1
  SET DATEFIELD = ''2013-07-15''
  WHERE JOBID = ''00-00-111111'');
```

While the `UPDATE OPENQUERY` syntax you're using is supported for SQL Server linked servers, I'm not sure that's true for other platforms such as PervasiveSQL...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I update table sin Oracle from SSMS.

The Linked server name in this case is `MyLinkedServer`.

I am updating the column `CONTACT_EMAIL` to `MyEmail@MyDomain.COM` where the `STATE` is one of the following `(KY,OH,NY,PA,VA,DC)`:

```sql
UPDATE L 
SET L.CONTACT_EMAIL ='MyEmail@MyDomain.COM'
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT * from MyTable')L
WHERE L.STATE IN('KY','OH', 'NY','PA','VA','DC')
```

`OPENQUERY` method works perfectly.